# Batch file to play music each time when certain application opens up in Windows 10?

Tags: batch-file

I have a challenging problem.

my requirement for batch script,

1. check whether Firefox browser is running..
2. And if it is running batch script will play a music.
3. Script will stay awake until browsing session completes & user closes the browser. (Script will never exits ever since system booted up until the shutdown. Means always stay awake to play the music each & every time user opens up Firefox browser)

Following is the script I've written,

```
@echo off

: loop
tasklist /fi "imagename eq Firefox.exe" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (start "C:\Program Files\KMPlayer 64X\KMPlayer64" "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Apple.mp3") else (goto loop)
// no exit
```

This script only runs for the first time and it does not loop. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
@echo off
title Firefox Watcher
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "MusicPlay="

:Loop
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq Firefox.exe" /NH 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "firefox.exe" || goto NoFirefox

if defined MusicPlay goto WaitTime
start "" "%ProgramFiles%\KMPlayer 64X\KMPlayer64.exe" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Apple.mp3"
if not errorlevel 1 set "MusicPlay=1"
goto WaitTime

:NoFirefox
if not defined MusicPlay goto WaitTime
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskill.exe /IM KMPlayer64.exe >nul 2>nul
set "MusicPlay="

:WaitTime
cls
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C NY /N /T 5 /D N /M "Stop watching Firefox [N/y]?"
if not errorlevel 2 goto Loop
if defined MusicPlay %SystemRoot%\System32\taskill.exe /IM KMPlayer64.exe >nul 2>nul

endlocal
```

There could used for the command block below label `WaitTime` also just:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NOBREAK >nul
goto Loop
```

That results in a timeout of five seconds without a user prompt to stop watching Firefox with waiting only up to five seconds for the user input before running the check on running *Firefox* once again.

A wait time with **CHOICE** or **TIMEOUT** (or **PING**) is necessary to pause batch script execution for some time like five seconds as otherwise the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` would execute the commands in the batch file again and again as fast as possible which means `cmd` would use one core of the CPU at 100% and would make really lots of file system accesses because of starting the executable **TASKLIST** again and again without any longer pause between the executions. That would not be good for the entire computer performance on which the music player runs and *Firefox* wants also CPU performance and access to the file system.

It would be better to replace the shortcut to start *Firefox* by a shortcut which starts `cmd.exe` with the command line to start the music player as separate process, run *Firefox* and wait for its self-termination and then terminate the music player. That would be more efficient.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `taskkill /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `timeout /?`
- `title /?`

See also:

- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul`, `2>nul` and `|`.
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of conditional operator `||`.